# Pattern Matching in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, pattern-matching, neo4j-apoc

Assume that in an application, the user gives us a graph and we want to consider it as a pattern and find all occurrences of the pattern in the neo4j database. If we knew what the pattern is, we could write the pattern as a Cypher query and run it against our database. However, now we do not know what the pattern is beforehand and receive it from the user in the form of a graph. How can we perform a pattern matching on the database based on the given graph (pattern)? Is there any apoc for that? Any external library?

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this is to decompose your input graph into edges and create a dynamic cypher from it. I have worked on this quite some time ago, and the solution below is not perfect but indicates a possible direction.
For example, if you feed this graph:

[image]

and you take the id(node) from the graph, (i am not taking the rel ids, this is one of the imperfections)

this query

```
WITH $nodeids AS selection
UNWIND selection AS s
WITH COLLECT (DISTINCT s) AS selection
WITH selection,
     SPLIT(left('a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z',SIZE(selection)*2-1),",") AS nodeletters
WITH selection, 
     nodeletters, 
     REDUCE (acc="", nl in nodeletters | 
       CASE acc 
         WHEN "" THEN acc+nl 
         ELSE acc+','+nl 
       END) AS rtnnodes
MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) IN selection
WITH COLLECT(n) AS nodes,selection,nodeletters,rtnnodes
UNWIND nodes AS n
UNWIND nodes AS m
MATCH (n)-[r]->(m)
WITH DISTINCT "("
    +nodeletters[REDUCE(x=[-1,0], i IN selection | CASE WHEN i = id(n) THEN [x[1], x[1]+1] ELSE [x[0], x[1]+1] END)[0]]
    +TRIM(REDUCE(acc = '', p IN labels(n)| acc + ':'+ p))+")-[:"+type(r)+"]->("
    + nodeletters[REDUCE(x=[-1,0], i IN selection | CASE WHEN i = id(m) THEN [x[1], x[1]+1] ELSE [x[0], x[1]+1] END)[0]]
    +TRIM(REDUCE(acc = '', p IN labels(m)| acc + ':'+ p))+")" as z,rtnnodes
WITH COLLECT(z) AS parts,rtnnodes
WITH REDUCE(y=[], x in range(0, size(parts)-1) | y + replace(parts[x],"[","[r" + (x+1))) AS parts2,
     REDUCE (acc="", x in range(0, size(parts)-1)  | CASE acc WHEN "" THEN acc+"r"+(x+1) ELSE acc+",r"+(x+1) END) AS rtnrels,
rtnnodes
RETURN 
    REDUCE (acc="MATCH ",p in parts2 | 
      CASE acc 
        WHEN "MATCH " THEN acc+p 
        ELSE acc+','+p 
      END)+
      " RETURN  "+
      rtnnodes+","+rtnrels+ 
      " LIMIT "+{limit} 
      AS cypher
```

returns something like

```
cypher: "MATCH (a:Person)-[r1:DRIVES]->(b:Car),(a:Person)-[r2:KNOWS]->(c:Person) RETURN a,b,c,r1,r2 LIMIT 50"
```

which you can feed to the next query.

In Graphileon, you can just select the nodes, and the result will be visualized as well.

Disclosure : I work for Graphileon

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have two issues: 1- Does your solution take attributes of the nodes or edges into account? 2- I did not understand this: "and you take the id(node) from the graph, (i am not taking the rel ids, this is one of the imperfections)"

Comment: @Shayan  1) no it does not  2) the $nodeids is a parameter (array) that holds the ids from the node in the subgraph. Please note, the query I posted it from work I did about 5 years ago, and is merely to indicate to you the direction. To take rels and properties into consideration, you will need to extend the query, but the principle is the same, i.e.  decompose the input graph, and construct a a dynamic cypher.

Comment: since it is work from long ago, using the apoc library may help to sanitize the query a bit  ;)

Comment: Okay. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have used patterns in genealogy queries.

The X-chromosome is not transmitted from father to son. As you traverse a family tree you can use the reduce function to create a concatenated string of the sex of the ancestor. You can then accept results that lack MM (father-son). This query gives all the descendants inheriting the ancestor's (RN=32) X-chromosome.

```
match p=(n:Person{RN:32})<-[:father|mother*..99]-(m) 
with m, reduce(status ='', q IN nodes(p)| status + q.sex) AS c 
where c=replace(c,'MM','') 
return distinct m.fullname as Fullname
```

I am developing other pattern specific queries as part of a Neo4j PlugIn for genealogy. These will include patterns of triangulation groups.

[GitHub repository for Neo4j Genealogy PlugIn](https://github.com/waigitdas/Neo4j-Genealogy-PlugIns)

Comment: Is that general-purpose or is it focused on genealogy?

Comment: that query is specific to genealogy, but the principle is generic: filter out the pattern from a collection of paths.